# Monitor 1 leaking into Monitor 2? Dual Monitor Setup

Tags: display, xorg, monitors

Yesterday I was trying elementaryOS with a liveusb and I noticed monitor 1's space was taking a thin string of space of monitor 2, I tried fiddling with the display settings and resolutions but didn't found a fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You totally ruined my dual monitor setup for me because I immediately noticed the same issue after reading your question.
In my setup, this might be related to the proprietary NVidia drivers and the different resolutions of the monitors.
I found the easiest way to fix this is by using [ARandR](https://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/).
The best tool to apply this configuration whenever connected to the external monitor is [autorandr](https://github.com/phillipberndt/autorandr).

1. Install ARandR and autorandr with the following command in Terminal.

```
sudo apt -y install arandr autorandr
```

2. Open ARandR from the Applications Menu.
   ARandR will show your current monitor configuration.
   My default, dual-monitor configuration is shown below.
   My primary monitor is the external one, *HDMI-0*, which is positioned to the left of my secondary monitor, *LVDS-0*.
   The slight overlap appears on the left edge of my secondary monitor, *LVDS-0*, though this overlap is not reflected in ARandR.

[image: Default Dual Monitor Configuration in ARandR]

Tip: You can increase or decrease the layout's size from the *View* menu.

3. Click and drag your secondary monitor a smidge away from your primary monitor. In my case, I clicked and dragged my secondary monitor, *LVDS-0*, and moved it slightly to the right like so.

[image: Corrected Dual Monitor Configuration in ARandR]

4. Click the green check mark to apply your settings.

[image: Clicking the Green Checkmark in arandr]

This removed the overlap in my dual monitor setup.

5. Now, you'll probably want to have this overlap fixed whenever you connect to this external monitor.
   This is where autorandr comes in.
   From the Terminal, save the current autorandr configuration with a descriptive name.
   Here I save my current configuration with the generic name *external*.

```
autorandr --save external
```

Now the overlap should be fixed whenever my laptop is plugged in to my external monitor, at least for my user account.

Comment: Haha yeah it's a bit annoying when you notice it, I will try solution thanks, I had this problema as well with other distros but never bothered trying to find a solution since I didn't stay with them long enough